# Instant messaging on Android/iOS app who have a Rails backend

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, chat

I'm new to rails and mobile development. What I want is a way to do instant messaging between my users on the android and iOs application.

As a backend, I use a rails 4 app, both of my mobile application communicate with it. For the moment I'm able to register and login user.

Now I want to be able to chat on private with different users like on the facebook chat.

I don't know if it can be done using my backend or I need a dedicated service to do this ?

Thank's

Comment: Were you able to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are may ways to do this.

**Server-Sent Events**

In rails 4 you can use ActionController::Live to do this.
This blodpost explains how.
[is it live?](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html)

**Polling for Changes**

This is a bit outdated. You basically at a set interval check if there are changes on the server. This means that there will be a lot of traffic to the server. If you want to scale it's perhaps not the best solution.

**Keep a websocket open**

There are many ways to do this here are some

[socket.io](http://socket.io/): raw Websocket for NodeJS

[websocket-rails](http://websocket-rails.github.io/): Plug and play WebSocket support for ruby on rails.

[faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/): Complete Bayeux Protocol for NodeJS/Rails with a Ruby-Server

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

No reason you can't do it with your Rails app. My advice would be to create a controller on the Rails side for sending and receiving messages in JSON format. Make sure it's only accessible to authorized users of course. You'll obviously also need a model for your messages linked to your users.

Then, on the iOS/Android side use simple GET's and PUT's to receive and send messages. That should get you going.

Comment: that won't be 'instant' messaging, also it does not address the problem of messages being sent/pushed to a mobile client